# How to check if the field in embedded schema is empty in Dreamweaver Template Building Block

Tags: tridion

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. I am creating the Dreamweaver TBB for a component. In my component some of the fields are empty. But in my component TBB, I want to check if the field is empty and I should not render it. If field is not empty then I should render and display the value.I am facing the problem when checking the content of subfield in embedded field.

On my component there is one multi-value embedded schema field with name "EMBFIELD". The EMBFIELD schema has a text field with the name "text". I want to check if the text field is empty or not. If it is not empty I have to iterate over the field to render the values.

I have to render the field by "RenderComponentField" only. When I tried rendering it is showing some error that the field doesn't exist.

I thought that this can be done using If block.

```
 <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.EMBFIELD" --> 
     <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.EMBFIELD" -->
           <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.EMBFIELD.text" --> 
                 <div>@@RenderComponentField("Component.Fields.EMBFIELD.text",TemplateRepeatIndex)@@</div>
            <!-- TemplateEndIf -->      
     <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
 <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

But it's giving error like

> Internal error: Context component Component  does not have field Component.Fields.conditionalText.text

Comment: If you're doing static publishing in Tridion 2011 SP1 you really should check out the Razor Mediator - more powerful and cleaner template code. It even comes with an installer for the CMS.

Razor Mediator Code Sample:

@if(Component.Fields.IntroField != ""){
  <span>@Component.Fields.IntroField</span>
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `StringLength(object parameter)` function, it will return 0 if the field is empty or if the string length of the parameter could not be determined. So all in all it should look like this:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="StringLength(Component.Fields.Field) > 0" -->
 <b>Value is not empty<b>
 <p>@@Component.Fields.Field@@</p>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

This might be the answer to your updated question:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.EMBFIELD.text" --> 
     <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.EMBFIELD" -->
            @@RenderComponentField("EMBFIELD[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].text", 0)@@       
     <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
 <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Comment: @user978511.I am actually using site Edit. To enable site edit I think we need to @@RenderComponentField("aaaa",0) rather that@@Field@@.

If you can provide how to use RenderComponentField to retrieve data, it will help.

Comment: @user978511.Thank you very much, its working so fine.It would be a pleasure if you could extend this to two embedded schemas. Say we have one more embedded subfield which is also embedded one.

In this case EMBFIELD has one more field such as embfield2. can you say how to iterate over.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use the Dreamweaver conditional regions to check for a value before you attempt to render it.

For example:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.Field" -->
    @@Component.Fields.Field@@
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue with the same error while accessing the embedded schema field and after tons of back and forth with the builder and debugging dwt understood that the error is about NOT putting a space between the last double qoute and the --> in the TemplateBeginIf statement. : 
Errors out by DWT Mediator:

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="EMBEDFIELD.internalLink || EMBEDFIELD.externalLink || EMBEDFIELD.label"-->
```

The below doesn't error out:

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="EMBEDFIELD.internalLink || EMBEDFIELD.externalLink || EMBEDFIELD.label"<PUT_A_SPACE_HERE>-->
```

It may be any TemplateBeginIf surrounding the RenderComponentField statement getting errored out.
Hope this helps someone